# Searching with Cortana

Tags: c#, xaml, voice-recognition, voice, cortana

I want to make an online media search application with cortana integration.
The user would simply ask: `MediaApp, look for videos named {songName}`
Where songName can be anything you could imagine.

Is this possible? Can you direct me to some information on this.
At the moment the only thing I was able to do was to define a `<PhraseList>` with items. I know you can dynamically modify voice command definition phrase lists but that won't help to me as I cannot possibly know all the things a user might search for in advance.

What I want to achieve is actually something simillar to searching the web with cortana only that I would search through media sites and display the result in a background message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<PhraseTopic Label = "songName" Scenario = "Dictation">` element instead of `<PhraseList>` in order to fetch the complete data from user input.

Now You'll get a SpeechRecognitionResult object, use SemanticInterpretation to get the data stored in "songName"